# Finding this Power Series's Interval of Convergence

Tags: real-analysis

We consider the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ where $a_n = \frac{2^k}{k}$ if $n$ is even, and $0$ otherwise.

I understand how to find that this series has radius of convergence $R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. What I don't understand is how to now find its interval of convergence. I know I'm supposed to plug $R$ into $x$ in the power series, but I'm having trouble moving on from there.

Comment: What's $k$? Is it perhaps $k=n/2$ when $n$ is even?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{2^k}{k} & \text{if $n=2k$ is even} \\[4px]
0 & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
Then you can rewrite your series as
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{k}x^{2k}
$$
Apply the ratio test (for $x\ne0$):
$$
\left|\frac{2^{k+1}x^{2k+2}/(k+1)}{2^kx^{2k}/k}\right|=\frac{2(k+1)}{k}|x^2|
$$
which has limit $2|x^2|=2x^2$. We know that the series converges when the limit is $<1$ and diverges when the limit is $>1$, so the series converges for
$$
2x^2<1
$$
that is, $-1/\sqrt{2}<x<1/\sqrt{2}$. The radius of convergence is thus $1/\sqrt{2}$.

Hadamard's criterion says that the radius of convergence is
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}
$$
which is usually more complicated to compute. But when the ratio test or the root test is successful, the radius of convergence can be determined more easily.

If you consider
$$
g(y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{k}y^k
$$
which has radius of convergence $1/2$, then, for $|y|<1/2$,
$$
g'(y)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^ky^{k-1}=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2y)^k=\frac{2}{1-2y}
$$
(geometric series).

It follows that
$$
g(y)=-\log(1-2y)+c
$$
Since $g(0)=0$, we conclude $g(y)=-\log(1-2y)$. Therefore your series can be summed as well, because $f(x)=g(x^2)$, yielding
$$
f(x)=-\log(1-2x^2)
$$
The series converges only on $(-1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 0):

The interval of convergence is $(c-R, c+R)$, where $c$ is the center of the series and $R$ is the radius of convergence. The series may also converge at $R$ or $-R$, which you have to check independently. Your series is centered at $0$.

**Edit:** *Why?* A power series will always converge at $c$ (the sum will just be $a_0$). Now if the series converges elsewhere, then $\exists r \in (0,\infty)$ s.t. the series converges whenever $|x-c|<r$ and diverges otherwise. This is stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Radius_of_convergence).

Comment: In this case it's $(c - R, c + R)$, though, since the power series diverges for $x = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. I'm having trouble understanding why this is true.

Comment: @Jake see my edit

Answer (score 0):

By what Frenchmen call Abel’s lemma (I do not know about other countries), the interval of convergence is the set of all $x$ such that the power series converges. It is contained in $[-R,R]$ and contains $(-R,R)$. 
So you just have to check whether the series converges for $x=R$ and $x=-R$.

Edit: On the other hand, you might want to check your computations, because, as is, $R=1/2$.